# SSRS report font problem on deployed reports

Tags: ssrs

I have created several reports for my SQL Server Reporting Services 2008 SP2 server, using Visual Studio 2008 on my machine.

The reports objects all use Arial as their font, in various sizes and weights.

When I test them in VS, all looks fine, and I can print them and export them okay.

When I deploy them to the server though, they look fine on-screen and if exported to PDF, but when printed directly from the web viewer, the fonts seem to go 'missing' - all the characters are squashed together as if there was a slight negative character-offset.

Answer (score 0):

Are you or might someone else be connecting to the server via RDP? I have seen RDP mess witht eh aspect ratio of fonts before. But this is just a shot in the dark.

Comment: Someone else being logged in remotely can break the global font rendering when printing?  Interesting.  I'd have to check that...